What can a time traveler use to generate an encryption key to encrypt information so it's only decryptable after a given time period
I have a time traveler basically dropping a few computers with a sort of technological uplift program into the 1980s. These computers have information about future science and technology, along with what guides and advice for how to most efficiently go from 1980s era technology to future technological level. Every computer has identical  information and they are spread out across the world with the intent that all this information become publicly accessible to everyone.
Our time traveler also wants to make sure that certain information is not immediately available despite encouraging disbursing of data to everyone. They want some information to only become accessible at certain time periods. To do this, I'm imagining they encrypt this data and then provide instructions on how to generate the key required to decrypt it, but with the intent that the information required to generate the key would not be available until the desired time period.
Since the butterfly effect is in full force, I imagine they would most likely use something like astrological observations and measurements, things that happened long ago and thus can't really be changed by recent human technological development, for generating this key.
My question is how well can they reliable create such a key, and what measurements should they use? They want to ensure no one can access this information until time X, meaning they need a large key to prevent any attempt to brute-force the encryption. They also need to be able to adjust for error bands to ensure that those generating the key will always generate the exact same key without getting bits wrong because their sensors weren't perfectly calibrated etc.  Ideally they would have a means where they could generate a key for any time X by simply loading historical recordings from that time and generating a key, so that means it not be dependent on rare astrological conditions.

Is this "I don't want you to access this information until exactly this time" or "I don't want you to access this information until you've reached a certain tech level"? Each of these would lead to different techniques.

Use an algorithm that was cracked in whatever year you want and was secure before that.

Not sure if this is the sort of thing you’re looking for (hence comment, not answer), but for encryption key use the winning lottery ticket numbers on a specific date or dates

I’m not convinced that knowledge alone would have any affect. Consider how many ideas never take off because they’re ahead of their time. Knowledge is only useful when the civilization has sufficient technology level to use the knowledge. For example knowledge about computers wouldn’t help first century Romans much as they’d lack the ability to fabricate a computer (among other things). So you’d first need to establish that in the 80s we’d have gotten much farther ahead if only we’d known what we know today. That seems unlikely TBH.

That said this could easily be flipped in the other direction by a villain: information at the wrong time can easily be quite destructive. Or you could use it as a device whereby well-meaning people or the hero meant to do good by passing knowledge to the past but caused absolute havoc in the present as a result and now the hero has to fix the mess.

Wait! If your protagonist is a time traveler, why do they need a time lock? Wouldn't it be simpler to to visit the time when they want the information to become available, and release it then?

Out of curiosity, why not base it on the technology itself? The butterfly effect can change everything. Maybe they reach the 'end' of the current technology. If they are ready, they can receive the next technology. They are thus guided to a certain outcome, and only with sufficient knowledge of that outcome they can decrypt the next batch. That will be a more flexible way to approach such butterfly world.

That's not how encryption works.   Any encryption scheme can be broken given sufficient time.     Not to mention that it's trivial to reset a computer's internal clock and make the OS "think" it's 10 years in the future.

If he is a full-time many when's time traveller he should know when most encryption schemes were developed and first put into commercial application. He/She then picks the one youngest at this needed date. It can't be used before invention and soon the new and better one is a best choice.

Astrology will not help. Astronomy might. Please don't confuse those two

@user7761803 lottery is extremely vulnerable to Butterfly Effect, since the roll of the lot is completely random, and even a nanosecond delay in its launch would roll different lots. Any change to the timeline would obliterate all Lottery outcomes and replace them with different ones.

@SolomonSlow didn't want to bog down the question with too much details, but the simple answer is the time traveler doesn't have that much control over his time travel.  He can't just pop back in every decade.

Search for "time-lock encrytpion" and "time capsule cryptography"

@
planetmaker
Actually, given that the question is about time travel, Astrology is the better bet. Even reading tea leaves for the key. Render onto fantasy what is fantasy, and onto science what is science.

Anything known about the future will inevitably change the future. That makes this question unanswerable. It is all about a MacGuffin, and MacGuffins are by definition undefined.

Novas
About ten novas occur every year in the Milky Way. Many occur near the Galactic Center, but sufficiently many occur nowhere near it.
With the current scare about quantum computers the time traveller will want a 256 bit key, of course.
Each nova has a well-defined position in the sky, given as right ascension H₁H₂ hours M₁M₂ minutes S₁S₂ seconds (0 h to 24 h) and declination d₁d₂ degrees m₁m₂ minutes s₁s₂ seconds (−90° to +90°). The time traveller gives the following rule to derive the key for the period year n to year n + 4:

Take the first 16 novas which occur in the given five year period farther away than five degrees from the Galactic Center, and which are brighter than the 9th magnitude or so, sufficiently bright to be easily observable with binoculars.

You may get a few which are borderline around the 9th magnitude; this only means that you may have to do the calculations several more times, with them included or not, until you find the correct key. It is not a big deal.

For each of the 16 novas write the decimal number H₁H₂M₁M₂S₁S₂d₁d₂m₁m₂s₁s₂ and represent in binary as a low-endian 64 bit integer.

Concatenate the 16 binary numbers to get a string of 128 octets.

Take the SHA-256 checksum of the binary string.

This will give you 256 bits. Use the key to decrypt the chunk of the Melontopaedia for the period.


(I am grateful to @SurpriseDog for suggesting to concatenate the numbers before taking the SHA-256 checksum.)
Novas cannot be predicted in advance. There are more than 16 bits of randomness in their coordinates. Astronomers will have zero difficulty in measuring their coordinates to the second. (They usually measure them with much greater precision.) The proposed rule effectively specifies a completely unpredictable 256-bit number.
(For the nit-pickers: the years are taken from 0:00:00 January 1st UTC to just before 24:00:00 December 31st UTC. The RA and declination are relative to the J2000 epoch; note that the J2000 epoch was defined in 1976, so it was already usable in the 1980s.)
Happy technolifting!

Why not just concatenate the H₁H₂M₁M₂S₁S₂d₁d₂m₁m₂s₁s₂,  from all thr novas combined into a single sha256 sum and use that as the key? What is the rationale for truncating each hash individually?

@SurpriseDog: So that you can swap them around if maybe one nova was not observed? On the other hand, why not? I just made up a rule. It's not as if I had a whole committee at NATA (the National Time Administration) devising a rule for me while planning the mission.

@SurpriseDog: You are right and I have updated the answer.

@AlexP If you're concerned about missed observations, Shamir's secret sharing provides a method such that only $m$ of $n$ observations are required to unlock the information, for whatever $m$ the encrypter chooses.

Do we have anything besides novas which is similarly impossible to predict and unaffected by humans? Position and strength of the magnetic north pole maybe? Timing of celestial bodies? (3 body problem makes it impossible to predict accurately into the future)

Problem: Because observation of novas requires specialized telescopes, and those are rare, I believe it would be pretty easy for a few world governments to quarantine that information. Hubble info doesn't have to be shared with the world... Discovery Telescope doesn't have to be shared... it's only by convention that their data is open because today that data doesn't have massive military implications. I think this is a poor fit because it isn't information that can be easily obtained by everyday individuals.

@SRM: You don't need the Hubble to observe novas which occur in our own galaxy. Any decent-sized telescope will do. The EU has astronomical observatories, Russia has astronomical observatories, China has astronomical observatories. Even hobbyists routinely build 1 meter telescopes. Sky gazing is really a popular activity.

@Michael: Yes, there are other phenomena which can substitute, but novas are easy to observe and there are millions of amateur astronomers in the world.

This looks to me like a very complicated variant of "the password is the aggregated numbers of the winning lottery tickets on 10 consecutive weeks, starting ".

@FrançoisJurain: By introducing knowledge ahead of time, the time traveller has changed history. In the new timeline there won't be the same lotteries and lottery numbers as in the original timeline. This is why they need to use impredictable but reliable phenomena which are not influenced by human history.

I see your point. The lottery must have taken place, and its result have been wandering among the galaxies, before the time-traveler started spreading anachronisms.

Wow, this is a marvelously clever solution that could be used almost indefinitely.

"Take the first 16 novas which occur in the given five year period" - the distance from Earth to the center of the Milky Way is 26 Kyears... Also, different novas may become visible from Earth in a different order than their occurrence.

The novas themselves are reasonably outside the time-traveller’s causality cone, so shouldn’t be affected by any change in history.  But their time and position, as measured from Earth, isn’t quite so robust — anthropogenic processes are measurably affecting the Earth’s orbit. Presumably either we need to know that this effect is small enough not to affect the keys, or else use a co-ordinate system independent of it (eg atomic time, solar ascension/declination).

You can fit the time of the observation in those 64 bits as well. And SHA is a fast hash algorithm, recommended hash for password is currently Argon2. It will prevent brute force attacks further. The time traveler could set the algorithm parameters suitable for the computers of the target time: 4 TB memory usage and 4bn iterations. Maybe there's an algorithm not yet invented that's even better!!

Maybe I'm missing something but if you ask someone to concatenate the last 5 novas then wouldn't that mean that If I know the last 4 novas I've now lowed the number of bits of complexity down to 12 bits to guess the last nova?  Meaning I could easily bruteforce the key without observing the last nova?  It seems that one could break your key with only 4 or even 3 novas known allowing access to the information years in advance of the intended date could they not?

@dsollen: Yes, if know the first four novas, then all you have is to try about 9 trillion combinations, which is trivial. If you know the first three, then you have to try about 10²⁶ combinations, which may be quite feasible. But this is not the point. The goal is to protect each chunk of the Melontopedia until its time comes; when its time has come and the first two novas have been observed then the race is on to unlock the next chunk a few months in advance. It may even become a sort of international competition.

@AlexP but you do need a big scope (not specifically Hubble) to do a full sky survey to find ALL the novas in order to know which one happened at which time to use as the cypher key. A background scope can look at one known nova and observe it. Finding one that is unknown? Much harder. Finding all or most? Impossible.

@SRM: Robotic telescopes which scan the full sky have existed for a long time. (And most usually they are not really all that big. Big telescopes have very small tiny fields of view.) Anyway, you can always put a lowe limit on brightness. I have edited the article to specify "brighter than the 9th magnitude".

@AlexP I am aware of state of telescope tech. The magnitude limit helps your answer considerably. I still have concerns about the ability of any non-pro to do scans 24-7 looking for these events, but I’ll concede it’s viable. Still, if I’m looking for holes in this story, it’s with ability of a few governments to suppress the nova info from general distribution. I still think that’s a weakness of this design.

small note this only works if you give them the HMS measuring system and callender, said system could develop diffrently if you did not, HMS is an arbitrary measurment system. If they drew the internation date line somewhere slightly diffrent or usea diffrent dating system your whole key no longer works.

@John: Astronomy is very old and very conservative. The right ascension and declination coordinate system is thousands of years old; the time traveller is assumed to be arriving in the 1980s, so that they are absolutely certain that this is commonly used. The hours-minutes-seconds of the right ascension specify an angle, not a time, and have nothing to do with solar time or time zones; the angle is measured from the position of the vernal equinox of the specified astronomical epoch.

@John: It would be perhaps more intuitive to give the right ascension in degrees, but the ancient Babylonian astronomers gave it in hours-minutes-seconds of sidereal time, and it has stuck. 24 hours of sidereal time make 360°, and that's it.

@AlexP i agree it is old, it also needs correction because of diffrences in mean and apprent sidereal  time, which time system is used, (TT, TAI, ET, ect)  But if you are using this for a decription key you can't have such corrections or they need to be known beforehand. Celestial coordinate system still need an exact date if you intent to extract specific numbers from it. it is still arbitrary in terms of the exact numbers unless you give them the coordinate system.

@John: Right ascension has nothing to do with time. It is an angle measured from a well-defined position. The "exact date" is the astronomical epoch, which is specified as J2000. (And converting from one epoch to another is quite easy.) (Yes, there is a celestial coordinate system which is time dependent; it is the horizontal coordinate system, altitude and azimuth. But the horizontal coordinate system is explicitly dependent on the time and place of observation; you wil never see horizontal coordinates in a catalog.)

Use timers
A slight frame challenge, as I would opt not to use the users to decrypt anything.
Relying on the people themselves to unlock it is very dangerous. They could miss it thanks to fate, like a power outage the moment you want to measure gravitational waves or a nova explosion. They could also find ways to get the information early if they break in with some unforseen method.
The answer is refreshingly simple. There aren't any computers. There are just contraptions that are tamper proof. The contraptions have their own power source and sensors to detect any intrusion. It'll initiate a melt down if people try to physically open it, or see through it in any way. That might not discourage someone or some government from trying, with a small nuclear crater as a result. It is then a simple risk reward formula. The risk to have it melt down and lose all incredibly useful future data is too high.
At the right interval the contraption releases the data itself. All data has been decoded by the contraption and send via an easy method. Think a computer of non-future components, send it out over a simple radio band, or even just printed out on a piece of paper.
The least amount of interaction you offer, the least amount of interfering you can have. The scenarios are already set by you. As no one can interact with the contraption, no one can guess an encryption or force their way through. Any attempt to try so is discouraged disproportionately. Smart people will realise that the only way to access the information safely is to wait for the next message.
Just add a manual so people know what it is and be very clear what will happen if you try to tamper with it, without revealing how it would do it.

except this also creates a ransom system, anyone can ransom the data by threatening to destroy the data.

@John though an intriguing thought, how would this 'anyone' get close enough to do anything? It'll probably be guarded better than a nuclear silo. Governments might be able to use their ample resources, but governments probably use the MAD strategy here. If theirs blow, all blow. But lets say someone does hostage the data. How will they show their claim is real, or how will they get away with i? multiple governments have a stake in it, so it is in their best interest to bring them to justice regardless of the outcome.

I'm talking about a government, most likely a dictator. its the same reason we don't want certain governments to get nukes, becasue they will use the threat of usage since they care more about their power then the downsides.

Low Tech solution...
In Flann O'Brian's 'The Dalkey Archive', the eccentric genius de Selby reveals a plot to simultaneously make the air lifeless throughout the Earth using some substance he called DMP. How was he going to spread this all over the surface of the Earth to be triggered on the same day? He was going to use the Post Office.
If the time-traveller is not going to turn up in person on the day, and reveal their message, then they could use some similar low-tech solution. They could lodge documents with several lawyers for fail-safe, with instructions that they should not be opened until a certain date. That could give the key to a public, encrypted document. Or it might just give directions to where the document was hidden.
If you have an encrypted document, this would be a nice plot twist. Computer scientists might spend 20 years trying to brute-force crack the documents, only to find that the key had been written down all the time. And when they decrypt it, the first words should be...

Mairzy doats and dozy doats and liddle lamzy divey


FYI that header doesn't provide real resistance. I read about a case in the late 20th century where these cryptographers had cracked some Russian cryptographic monument but couldn't read the resulting spaceless wall of Russian text.

@Joshua True. Brute force techniques mostly need something to sort out the likely solutions from all the possible answers. Something that gives the right letter frequencies with spaces would be a good first sieve. A spell checker would be the logical next step. I assumed the actual encryption would be much too hard to crack by any techniques of the day.

How many times have you broken the 'Do Not Open Until Christmas' admonishment?

Provide a security token. That is, a tamper-proof hardware package that contains the secret. In your case, the token would contain a long-life power supply (maybe an RTG) and a clock; and it would not release the key until the clock has counted a sufficient number of ticks.
In the security business, it's generally recognized that there is no such thing as a lock that can't be broken, but they can do a pretty good job these days of creating containers that can't be opened without destroying their contents. That's especially true when the content is digital information.
Put a label on it that says, "If you are patient, you will be rewarded. If you are greedy and you try to open this before __date__, then you'll get nothing."

Combine the times of a number of events happening
So you want to have a long key, and room for error. You can’t do this with time of an event alone, let’s assume you bring AES, or something like it back in time and bundle it with it so that with a key, you can decrypt it, as encryption of the 1980s tended to not be very secure. With a 128 bit key, it would require accuracy down to roughly 10^-20 nanoseconds to generate a key. That’s not gonna happen.
So we need a way to take lower accuracy measurements, and combine them to create a long and hard to fake key.
One possible way to do this is the last few binary digits of the unix seconds at the time  an event occurs.
So for example, one part of it could be 111011100000 which is the last 12 bits of the Unix timestamp of GW170817. Then you can have a bunch of other specific events picked out and communicated, with the rough time and location to observe to find them. That’s because 12 bits of Unix timestamp only covers just over an hour, meaning you can tell people what day it happens, without actually giving anything away. With just 22 events using this, you can get a 256 bit key, standard for encryption nowadays. More events, or using more of the Unix timestamp would increase the security of it, without making it much if any harder to measure.

The answer from @Topcode is a good one.
First of all, AES (Rijndael) wasn't invented until 1998. Before that, 3DES was the major encryption algorithm in use. So, since neither the ISO number, winner of the AES algorithm competition or date of publication would be related to most things even considering the butterfly effect, it would be sufficient to give clues to look for: "Use the algorithm which will supersede 3DES". It is always obvious that 3DES would be replaced sooner or later, so that's not much of a giveaway. Instructions for how to decode timestamps as bits into the key could be given as clues.
Typical clues for timestamped or localized events that would be obvious when they occur, but impossible to guess in advance, could be

"Two timestamps on a Terrible Tuesday 2001" => The time of Twin Towers.
"Timestamp of bolide in Russia" => Chelyabinsk meteor.
"Date of perihelion for the discovery of July 23, 1995" => Hale-Bopp meteor.
"Timestamp of shake in 2009" => Thailand tsunami.
"From ashes to ashes, but where" => location of Eyjafjallajökull eruption.

Different timestamps can be described as "seconds/minutes/hours/days from date/time X", where X isn't necessarily Unix Epoch, but something that gives a reasonable number of unpredictable bits.
Naturally, there will be several failed attempts because of interpreting timestamps as UTC, local time, guessing wrong dates before the correct date arrives etc., but those mistakes are "few" compared to brute-forcing an entire timestamp. Either way, the development of non-technology-accelerated computer performance will naturally be limited, giving automatic protection against brute-force attempts.
Also, as time passes, the number of remaining bits to discover decrease, which of course would make it possible that someone actually brute-force the last set of bits rather than really waiting for it. In fact, there might be confusion because when the brute-forced timestamp finally happens, there is indeed nothing peculiar happening - because of the butterfly effect.

The attack on the WTC is definitely not going to happen at the same time (or even at all) if you change history that much, and neither is the development of AES. Tsunamis and volcanos are debatable - I don't think we know if interior Earth dynamics have enough of a butterfly affect to be affected by weather at the surface, but they might be. (Weather events will certainly be different in this time line.) Meteors and comets and so on are fairly safe though.


From ashes to ashes, but where → that's a tricky one. You rely on events but also in the ability of people to guess that this is what you meant. I would never think of that for instance (which does not say much about the quality of the hint, but is at least a warning)


You have to use events which are completely independent of human action and the only thing on your list is the Chelyabinsk bolide.  And the Hale Bopp one utterly doesn't work because you don't know the date of discovery.

If taking this "date of event" type approach, you would need to combine multiple dates rather than using a single date for a key. A single date, or even a date-time down to the second, is just too vulnerable to brute-force attacks. The estimated remaining lifespan of the Sun is about 2e12 days; if you know the key is a date within that span, you're looking at brute-forcing a 5-byte password, which can be done very very fast with current-day tech.

@G_B it would be preferable to do that the opposite way, by providing the timestamp and the event being the secret: "September 11 (two words)" -> "Twin Towers". "November 22, 1963 (three words)" -> "John Fitzgerald Kennedy". Assuming the events are deterministic despite time travel, or that the information itself won't cause issues (e.g. knowing that a relevant event will happen on that date, might have prompted for an agenda change, with JFK not going to Dallas that day).

@Ángel These kinds of secrets would be highly susceptible to brute-force attacks, and if a brute-force attack succeeds then as well as unlocking the encrypted material early the attacker is also getting advance notice of a major event that hasn't yet happened.

My idea is that all dates etc needs to be combined into one single key, so you would need everything to the key, So, 4-5 dates would be (depending on accuracy and representation format, lets say 3 bytes)=12 bytes=96 bits. Encode a position as 32 bits and you have a full AES key, decodeable no earlier than 2012. As of today, AES still is not brute-forcaeble.
I.e, in my examples, nothing that is done by the timetraveler, can affect the future before that date.
Modification by @Ángel with date->event name can also be interesting.

Digits of Pi
If you want the material released "when people are ready for it", use something that is hard to compute.  A typical example would be

Lesson 1 is encrypted using digits 10,000 through 10,999 of pi.
Lesson 2 is encrypted using digits 100,000 through 100,999 of pi.
Lesson 3 is encrypted using digits 1,000,000 through 1,000,999 of pi.

And so on.
Being able to compute this requires both good hardware and good algorithms. Both have been improving steadily  over the decades since computers arrived.
Unfortunately, people can calculate pi in secret and get a head start on the others, this might be against the wishes of the time traveller.
Still, given the speed of development, everybody should catch up within a year or two.

Many transcendental numbers work for this. Interesting thing would be use it as one time pad, meaning you take say each pair of digits and add or subtract it from each byte of encrypted message. In this case you could even partially solve messages.
Good side of one time pad is that you do not rely on cryptography going same way. As there is lot of possible options.

This method would be broken by the 21st century, unfortunately: after the discovery of the BBP formula for pi, we've since figured out the general pattern for algorithms that can generate arbitrary digits of irrational numbers in any base without needing to calculate all the preceding digits.

the other problem is if calculating pi suddenly becomes that important, there is going to be a LOT more investment of time and money in mathmatics. which will change when it is decripted. As soon as it is based on technology then that technology starts advancing faster.

I am afraid astrological events are very (extremely even) predictable on the scale of millenia or more - chaos will eventualy win, but not on the timescale we are talking about.
Bigger danger for the traveller's goal is that his manuals will be discarded as one of (sadly too many) crackpot writings, if he openly mentions astrology (and time travel, on top of that).
Otherewise, timing of events would be the best bet - astronomical events are the best, probably the orbital elements of hirtherto undiscovered comets, they might  provide handful of bits of information each. (Super)Novae are even better, since they are causally disconnected from recent history (unless the time travel brings works the "parallel universe way" and the rest of our observable universe might be  lightly different).
Your traveller might be tempted to use major climate events (memorable hurricanes, floods etc.), but due to butterflies they are unlikely to occur the same way second time. But, given the traveller is into astrology, would he even know this? Might be a good plot element.
Geological events (volcanoes, earthquakes) might be more reliable, but they are still causally within reach, so chaos still might rule.
Overall, I would not rely on the cryptography that much - too much data makes it easier to  crack the encryption. Instead, encode geographical location of dead drops, each one providing the next batch of knowledge.
There is also the method outlined in Robert L. Forward's Draggon's Egg, where the decryption bits come from the immediately preceding discovery -e.g. you find the next piece of quantum gravity theory if you measure some fundamental constant up to X digits (meaning you must have advanced accelerators first). You know the description of FTL travel is located in a secure box on the second planet of Proxima Centauri, etc.

Frame challenge.
Any specific prediction about the future that comes true (specific encryption keys that depend on currently unknowable values from the future) will inevitably be turned into a religion and any information attained in the process will be converted to some ideology or other. The Law of Unintended Consequences and the Law of Human Nature vs Science. High Priests of the past controlled the people because of their ability to predict eclipses, for instance, or the seasons.
When the Moon is in the Seventh House, ALL WILL BE REVEALED.
Astrology wins over Astronomy - using the stars in the heavens to predict human events and human fortunes. Foretelling the future by reading tea leaves.

Anything which is easily looked up after a given date but unknown before then. The birth name of Pope Sarah the Third, the official exact time of the first manned landing on a moon of Saturn, etc.
There are some extreme examples at the end of Robert Forward's book Dragon's Egg, where the nonhumans leave a set of scientific solutions in places where the humans would have to essentially solve the problem themselves before getting the exact/improved answer, as incentives to work toward finding those solutions.

The problem with this is that if the event is known, the manner in which the event unfolds may change. For example, if everyone knows that the first manned landing on a moon of Saturn is a key, some people may work either harder or not as hard on the applicable space program, or may even try to sabotage it, leading to either an earlier or a later landing.

You're presuming the key is widely known, is subject to human behavior, and that changing the past is possible. So pick your key as something that is not influenced by human behavior, or that can't be influenced with technology likely to be developed before the target time. Or have several keys do at least one of them is likely to survive disruption.

@Robert Columbia
And thus you have, perhaps unintentionally, elucidated the paradox of time travel. Anything that is known about the future ahead of time, will change the future.

@JustinThymetheSecond: According to one set of theories. According to another, the future is already the one the changes created. According to yet another, you can't change any past but your own. And so on, and so on. Read the literature for yet more variations.

Second frame challenge.
If you really think about it, according to the 'reversibility of time' notion in Physics that states, basically, that in any physics equation, time can be negative as well as positive, the one thing that is NOT covered by this is 'information'.
That is, maybe physical stuff can be sent back in time, in effect 'undoing' what forward time did. That is, chemical reactions go in reverse, undoing the change, gravity reverses, so things fall back up to where they started, stars un-burn their fuel, reverting to their former state, and so on, planets travel backwards in their orbits. Like a movie shown in reverse.
However, there are no provisions in these equations for sending information back in time, because, well, how do you 'undo' information? Physical stuff may be able to be 'undone', but not so much 'life'. If you send an encryption key back in time, then it reverts to - what? It certainly cannot exist as it is in the present, and there is no precedent for that encryption key - it did not 'come from' anything.

I suggest something simple.
Imagine you want to decrypt a file by 1992.
"XOR this XXX file with the digital track of the winner of Eurovision 1992".
The result of a XOR of the data (contained in a 5 inch disk) with the CD of the eurovision winner will be an HQX file containing a Mac PowerPC executable that would decrypt the data (maybe asking for some extra info in the process, such as "please insert this program in a Mac with CD unit and introduce the Nirvana Nevermind CD").
PowerPC chips were sold from 1992, so there is little risk reverse engineering can get the algorithm. Also, nobody would expect in the eighties an HQX containing code different from 68k.

Frame challenge: knowledge alone won’t likely help
I’m not convinced that knowledge alone sent into the past would have any significant positive impact. Consider how many ideas never take off because they’re ahead of their time. Knowledge is only useful when the civilization has sufficient technology level to use the knowledge. For example knowledge about the theoretical underpinnings of modern computers wouldn’t help first century Romans much as they’d lack the ability to fabricate a computer (among other things).
So you’d first need to establish that in the 80s we’d have gotten much farther ahead if only we’d known what we know today. That seems unlikely TBH because our technology level was quite a bit lower then (at least in areas you’re probably interested in exploring) and technological advancement takes time, and not just because we haven’t figured things out yet. It takes time to develop collective capabilities to put theory into practice as a civilization.
In the 80s our capability for manufacturing high density integrated circuits was significantly cruder than it is today. Memory restrictions on computers meant programs couldn’t be nearly as complicated, and you couldn’t just run computations longer as a workaround because computer speeds were atrocious compared to today. Modern AI was completely out even though neural networks go back at least to the 70s I believe. The list goes on and on.
The limiting factor in general wasn’t as much that people couldn’t figure out theory as it was that our technology level always limits what is possible and technological advancement is often quite slow. I’m not convinced you can realistically speed this process up with a few choice “knowledge bombs” sent into the past.

You are absolutely correct, bob, on a site other than this one. Very few around here actually care about reality and human behavior, they are so wrapped up in ideology  and mythological worlds, even those who profess 'hard science'. For instance, any information that contradicts the Religion of Einstein would immediately be discarded as heresy and ignored by many today. What we regard as 'useful knowledge' is always filtered by 'current ideology'. Our paranoia around hemp is another example. Any suggestion that CBD oil is beneficial would have been cast aside decades ago

the roman could absoluelty exploit the basic underpinnings of computers, indroducing electricity ot the romans would absolutley have an effect, and the romans could build a simple comuper if they knew how which would jumpstart a further precision allowing further development.

If you have them the manufacturing lines to produce wires and electrical components and everything that goes into a manufacturing line since the Romans lacked modern manufacturing so we’d have to bootstrap it, the skilled laborers to run the manufacturing lines from top to bottom, the schools to train new workers, etc. including out of the box tech and infrastructure to work with metal and glass in ways that were likely beyond the Romans then absolutely. If you just dropped a how-to guide in their laps then no b/c they’d have to first develop all the above and maybe more to quickly use it.

Yeah they could have eventually gotten there with the additional knowledge, but the truth is human nature is such that knowledge that isn’t useful now not expected to be useful in the foreseeable future tends to be disregarded, hence the “idea before it’s time” phenomenon. So if you have the Romans the epic how-to guide that they realized they couldn’t use without decades or even centuries of R&D and infrastructure building and workforce training, would they cherish it and work hard over so many years to implement it, or would they toss it in the trash?

If you really want the how-to guide to have a hope of being effective, it would need to give step-by-step instructions on how to at max speed get all necessary new infrastructure, logistics, educational, and tech capabilities in place, along with funding sources for all these new workers and all the raw materials, along with a clearly presented value proposition so that the decision makers of the day would decide that this massive effort would benefit them. And it would have to, which isn’t guaranteed. Are you sure that the benefits would outweigh the costs for the Romans to have electricity?

I just noticed that autocorrect changed “gave” on”have” in several places above but can no longer edit the comments.

Calculate the key by obtaining a hash from files of a particular software release in the future (like specific versions of Windows, Doom PC, etc).
For example, take some files from a Windows 95 release and use them to calculate a hash that can be used as a key.
If I gave you the computer in 1980, you don’t have a way to know what these files from Windows 95 will look like until they are released. And if the hash is big enough, you cannot brute force the key in an acceptable period.
The only problem with this method is the butterfly effect: if some people know what you're looking for, it could influence decisions and give you something different.

Butterfly effect. Someone makes a slight improvement in a compiler in 1993, thus every hash after that is thrown off.

Another example: if software gets improved in the 1980’s, then perhaps Windows ME wouldn’t exist at all (or at least it would look nothing alike).
